# Android Transform the current Fragment Class to Activity Class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that do somethings related to searchview it works well,

but I want to Create an activity to perform tasks typically as the fragment.

There is no problem with XMLs the main problem is in Java Code.Some methods in the fragment , i don't know the opposite of them in activity.

***Fragment Code:***

```
public class AirlineSearchFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
    private RecyclerView recyclerview;
    private List<AirlineData> airlinesDataModel;
    private AirlinesSearchViewAdapter adapter;

    public AirlineSearchFragment()
    {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.airline_search_fragment, container, false);

        recyclerview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();
        airlinesDataModel = new ArrayList<>();
        airlinesDataModel.addAll(AirlinesCore.airlinesList);
        adapter = new AirlinesSearchViewAdapter(airlinesDataModel);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.auto_complete, menu);

        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                        // Do something when collapsed
                        adapter.setFilter(airlinesDataModel);
                        return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                        // Do something when expanded
                        return true; // Return true to expand action view
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        final List<AirlineData> filteredModelList = filter(airlinesDataModel, newText);
        adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    private List<AirlineData> filter(List<AirlineData> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<AirlineData> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (AirlineData model : models) {
            if(model.arabicName==null)
            {
                model.arabicName="";
            }
            if(model.shortName==null)
            {
                model.shortName="";
            }
            if(model.name==null)
            {
                model.name="";
            }
            final String text = model.name.toLowerCase()+model.shortName.toLowerCase()
                    +model.arabicName.toLowerCase()+model.code.toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }


}
```

***My Activity with some methods copied from fragment(What should I add to it?):***

```
public class AirlinesSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    private RecyclerView recyclerview;
    private List<AirlineData> airlinesDataModel;
    private AirlinesSearchViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_airlines_search);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        final List<AirlineData> filteredModelList = filter(airlinesDataModel, newText);
        adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
    private List<AirlineData> filter(List<AirlineData> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<AirlineData> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (AirlineData model : models) {
            if(model.arabicName==null)
            {
                model.arabicName="";
            }
            if(model.shortName==null)
            {
                model.shortName="";
            }
            if(model.name==null)
            {
                model.name="";
            }
            final String text = model.name.toLowerCase()+model.shortName.toLowerCase()
                    +model.arabicName.toLowerCase()+model.code.toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try moving you logic in `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` to `Activity.onCreate()`. And override `onCreateOptionsMenu` in the Activity and copy the logic that you had in the fragment

Comment: Basically the activity and fragment lifecycles are quite similar. So you can move onCreateView and onCreate -> onCreate, onResume -> onResume, onPause -> onPause etc. where necessary. +1 to Juan for his answer.

Comment: Another option would have been to simply create an activity that contains that one fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving your logic in `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` to `Activity.onCreate()`.

Then override `onCreateOptionsMenu` in the Activity and copy the logic that you had in the Fragment